# Authenticating with OpenEMM Web services 2.0

Tags: c#, soap-client

Has anyone got any experience with working with the OpenEMM web services?

When ever I connect to the services I get the following error:

com.sun.xml.wss.XWSSecurityException: Receiver Requirement for Digested Password has not been met; nested exception is com.sun.xml.wss.XWSSecurityException: com.sun.xml.wss.XWSSecurityException: Receiver Requirement for Digested Password has not been met

Here is my web.config file:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="openemmSoap11">
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Digest" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://newsletter.********.co.uk/openemm-ws2/" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="openemmSoap11" contract="emmservice.openemm"
        name="openemmSoap11" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

(I had great fun installing an ssl certificate on apache)

Here is my implementation:

```
   var param = new[]
        {
            new MapItem {key = "email", value = "*******************"},
            new MapItem {key = "mailtype", value = "0"}, new MapItem {key = "gender", value = "0"}
        };

    var service = new AddSubscriberRequest
        {
            parameters = param,
            overwrite = false,
            doubleCheck = true,
            keyColumn = "email"
        };

    var request = new openemmClient();
    request.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "***********";
    request.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "********";
    request.Open();
    request.AddSubscriber(service);
    request.Close();
```

Any ideas where I could be going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

OpenEMM Web services 2.0 require creation of creation of nonce, timestamp and password encryption. Official documentation is [HERE](ftp://ftp.heanet.ie/disk1/sourceforge/o/op/openemm/OpenEMM%20documentation/Documentation%20%28latest%20versions%29/Webservice-API_2.0_EN_1.1.2.pdf)

You have no nonce nor password encryption first try documentation example

if you need help with implementation - ask!